# Arrays not working in my add_options_page

Tags: plugins

I'm customizing my own options page for a plugin and I have a very basic question about arrays that I'm attempting to input in my add_options_page under the $function. My code looks like this:

```
function myplugin_register_settings() {
    add_option('myplugin_option_name', 'Option Value');
    register_setting('myplugin_options_group', 'myplugin_option_name', 'myplugin_callback');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'myplugin_register_settings')

function create_plugin_settings_page() {
    add_options_page('Page Title', 'Plugin Menu', 'manage_options', 'myplugin', array( $this, 'plugin_settings_page_content'));
}
add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'create_plugin_settings_page'));

function plugin_settings_page_content() {
    echo 'Hello World';
}
```

Unfortunately when I remove the arrays my code works perfectly. I'd like to keep them included because I'm looking to input a text field that saves to the database. Anyone help me?

Comment: Are toy referring to these: `array($this, 'create_plugin_settings_page')`? They have nothing to do with being able to save text fields. They're how you define a [callback function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) that's part of a class instance. If you're not using a class you shouldn't be using an array or `$this`.

Comment: Yes, i apologize I'm just starting out. I will remove them since I am not using a class, unless you would recommend using a class? Do you have any tips as to how to get a text field to save? I can post the code to my add_settings_field as well.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that adds a text field, or saves it. You should work your way through the [Settings API documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/using-settings-api/).

Comment: Yes I know, I offered to post it because it is in a different part of my code. I will work on it thank you for your help!

Comment: It's important to always ask about the problem you're actually trying to solve, not your attempted solution. If you're having trouble getting text fields to save, you need to describe _that_ issue in the question, and include all relevant code. This thing about the arrays was ultimately not relevant, making this an example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Ok great, I just signed up. Thank you for your tips!